# How to extract the texts from the span tag as per the html using selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

I'm looking to pull the following information between the span/div tags from these three tags.

```
<span class="engagementInfo-valueNumber js-countValue">496.26K</span>

<div class="websiteRanks-valueContainer js-websiteRanksValue">
        <span class="websiteRanks-valueChange websiteRanks-valueChange--isSingleMode websiteRanks-valueChange--up"></span>
    180
</div>

<span class="websitePage-relativeChangeNumber">16.35%</span>
```

When I copy the xpath it turns out like:

```
/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/span[2]/span[2]/span
```

and copying the selector yields:

```
body > div.wrapper-body.wrapperBody--websiteAnalysis.js-wrapperBody > main > div > div > div.analysisPage-section.analysisPage-section--withFeedback.websitePage-overview.js-section.js-showInCompare.is-active.js-triggered > div.analysisPage-sectionContent.analysisPage-sectionVisits.js-sectionContent.js-print-pageFooter.is-triggered > div.u-clearfix.analysisPage-sectionOverview > div.websitePage-mobileFramed.websitePage-mobileFramed--overview > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > span.engagementInfo-value.engagementInfo-value--large.u-text-ellipsis > span.engagementInfo-valueRelative.websitePage-relativeChange.websitePage-relativeChange--delay.websitePage-relativeChange--up.js-showOnCount.is-shown > span
```

ultimately I would love a few elements with `496.26K`, `180` and `16.35%`, or in a list.

I've tried the following without success, though its worked for me for other websites in the past:

```
url = 'https://www.similarweb.com/website/' + domain
        driver.get(url) #get response
        driver.implicitly_wait(2) #wait to load content
        total_vists = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath='/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/section[2]/div/ul/li[1]/div[2]').text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try **css selector** for **first** span as :

for extracting `496.26K`

```
first_span = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.engagementInfo-valueNumber.js-countValue").text  

print(first_span)
```

for extracting `180` :

```
second_span= driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.websiteRanks-valueChange.websiteRanks-valueChange--isSingleMode.websiteRanks-valueChange--up")  

print(second_span.text)
```

for extracting `16.35%`

```
third_span= driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.websitePage-relativeChangeNumber")  

print(third_span.text)
```

Comment: You forgot the dots `.` for the classes in your last two CSS selectors.

Comment: @JeffC : I believe they are present. There are two spaces in second css selector and no space in last one. Oh yeah I forgot span. That prefix. My bad

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately. I'm getting `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span.engagementInfo-valueNumber.js-countValue"}`

Comment: Print this : print(len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(locator)))

Comment: and check for iframe too , the exception is for either the locator is wrong or element could be inside an iframe.

Comment: You don't *have* to have the `SPAN` but you are required to have the `.` to indicate that it is a class, e.g. `.websitePage-relativeChangeNumber` vs `websitePage-relativeChangeNumber`.

Comment: @JeffC : perfectly true.

Comment: @JeffC : but doesn’t it make more sense to use tag name such as div, span, ul, li etc when we are trying to write css selector based on class name . Cause A div and span could share the same class name and using tag name is a good way to differentiate between them. And it’s quite understandable that classes separated by spaces in class attribute are collections of multiple class.

Comment: @cruisepandey I have no problem with adding a tag name to a CSS selector. I usually do it for just the reason you mentioned. My only point was to say that you forgot the `.` to indicate the class name. I just wanted to make sure that when you added the tag name along with the period that you realized that it wasn't *required* as part of the CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

As perr the *HTML* you have shared as the elements are [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) based so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *elements to be visible* and you can use the following solutions:

- `496.26K`:

  ```
  engagementInfo = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='engagementInfo-valueNumber js-countValue']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```
- `180`:

  ```
  websiteRanks = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='websiteRanks-valueContainer js-websiteRanksValue']")))
  websiteRanksText = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', websiteRanks).strip()
  ```
- `16.35%`:

  ```
  websitePageChangeNumber = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='websitePage-relativeChangeNumber']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I'm getting a Timeout Exception when trying to run this :/

Comment: @MattW. _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of _failed expected-conditions_. Debug your code through `find_element_by_*` in-conjunction with `time.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.